# echo PHP variable within CSS

Tags: php, mysql, css, variables, echo

I'm trying to echo a php variable within my styles.php. This variable, which I defined in a separate (and included) php file, contains several values from a database :

```
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
if ($db_found) {
     $SQL = "SELECT NumDep, DENS FROM france WHERE DENS BETWEEN '0' AND '45' ";
     $result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
$dens = $db_field['NumDep'] . ",<BR>";
echo $dens;
```

When I echo the variable $dens in my index.php file, the 20 values are showing normally. But when I echo the $dens variable in my styles.php file, only the ***last*** value is printed.

```
<?php
echo $dens; ?> <?php echo "
{
   fill: #FFC285;
   fill-opacity:1;
   stroke:white;
   stroke-opacity:1;
   stroke-width:0.5;
   stroke-miterlimit: 3.97446823;
   stroke-dasharray: none;
}
```

What I want is to print the 20 values, in the same way they are printed in the index.php file.

Can anyone help me? (Alternative solutions for printing these values from the database into the styles.php are welcome!)

Thanks in advance. 
Jonas

Comment: As an aside: I hope you are using PHP to pre-process this CSS rather than executing it on every request. That is a huge was of resources.

Comment: `$dens = $db_field['NumDep'] . ",<BR>";` - you're putting HTML in a CSS file. Did you mean to use `\n` rather than `<br>`? Also, please consider switching to MySQLi or PDO for your queries, as the `mysql_` functions are now deprecated and considered insecure.

Comment: That's happening because in your `index.php` file you're outputting it **during a loop** whereas in your `styles.php` file you aren't, so it's just outputting the last result. I hate to think that you're going to print that CSS style for each database row, you should be assigning a class to the elements with those names and defining a single CSS class style.

Comment: @Marty I don't understand exactly what you mean. I think my css is generated by each request... is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead

```
$dens = $db_field['NumDep'] . "\n";
```

use

```
$dens .= $db_field['NumDep'] . "\n";
```

Comment: This will also work (assuming the `while` loop remains in index.php and was not there just to debug).

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` in your index.php is in a `while` loop, so it is printing multiple times. By the time you hit `styles.php`, the while loop is done, so the value of `$dens` is whatever it was at the end of the loop.

You need to use a `while` loop in your CSS for it to work as intended.

Comment: Note that I don't think this is a very good idea. That's just why you're having the issue that you are having.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I didn't find a better way to echo a range of IDs in my css, as these IDs should be easy to change (with the command BETWEEN to select specific fields in my database). Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I don't recall finding a _much_ better way in my PHP days, but .css.php files just make me shudder. If you can, I would try to refactor so you can dynamically assign classes (in a normal php file) that do what you want, instead of ever going the .js.php or .css.php route.

Comment: Ok I'll explore this. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looping through when doing the echo it will show every result. You need to mimic this in your CSS either with a while in the same way you have for the echo, or create an array of values in the while loop then loop through this later in your CSS.

Or you can append to `$dens` with `.=` instead of just `=` in your while loop

Answer (score 0):

After getting more involved in programming, I came to the conclusion that a possible answer to my question would have been: use d3.js instead of making things complicated with "dynamic CSS"!